# Given a $n \times n$ matrix has only one eigenvalue, what can I say about the Jordans?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

for example: I have a $6 \times 6$ matrix, with only one eigenvalue. How many "essentially different" Jordan forms can I have? How would I determine this for other eigenvalue multiplicities?

Comment: Have you played around with pen and paper to see what sizes of Jordan blocks you can arrange? This should very quickly lead you to your answer.

Comment: @Joppy I feel like I could make so many blocks. 6 of size 1. 2 of size 2, 2 of size 1, 3 of size 1, 1 of size 3, and permutations of these. Is there a way to see for $n \times n$ matrices?

Comment: You basically have your answer: once you rearrange the blocks from largest to smallest, you'll end up with what's called a partition of 6. This will generalise to $n$. I don't think there is an easy formula for counting the number of partitions of $n$ though.